# Advanced finding connected value in selected row list box

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, userform

I have in my userform listbox which display 10 columns. All rows have an individual ListIndex.
I would like to display f.e. in Msgbox value after select some row and click button "Show".
But this value is not avalible in listbox. So, I thought that all rows have individual ListIndex, I can use VLOOKUP for finding my target.
For example: I selected row no. 1 then ListIndex is 1 and this is my Look up Value. In my database sheet I have the same individual ID values.
Then of course, I have to declarate range, number of column and parameter "False".
Theoretically, I expect the result after that but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
  Dim indexno As Long 'this is my delcaration for finding Look up Value
  Dim myVLookupResult As Long 'this is my declaration for VLookup Result
  indexno = ListBoxResult.ListIndex  'my Lookup Value is dynamic and depend of selected row
  myVLookupResult = Application.VLookup(indexno, Worksheets("DataBase").Range("A1:J100"), 5, False)
  MsgBox myVLookupResult 'should display result of VLOOKUP
```

But the result is error: Run-Time error: 13 - Type mismatch.
I guess the problem is with convert type of Dim from int to string.

Someone could support me, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your vlookup result really number (long)? What happens if you leave declaration open? (Remove 'as long')

Comment: It a little bit help, but now the result are wrong. VLookUp in normal formula and VLookUp in VBA (the same parameters) have totally different results.

Comment: What do you mean by result is wrong? Can you provide example of how your data and listBox look?

Comment: I will try explain. So, in my sheet I have column A with ID number and column E with some reference values. For example: for ID=1 this value is PB123. And formula VLookup can find value "PB123" if lookup value is 1. In listbox also is displaying ok. But if I select row with ID=1 and use this code that return value is not "PB123". Is totally diffrent. btw. I made additional button for display ID numer in selected row and this function is always true.

Comment: And have you taking in account, that ListIndex is starting by 0? So ID=1 is 0, ID=2 is 1... Have you tried indexno = ListBoxResult.ListIndex + 1  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup value of a VLOOKUP worksheet function must be of the same data type as the data in which it is to be found. In your code the lookup value is of *Long* data type. If the column in which you are looking for it has text, the number you are looking for will not be found. So, you change the lookup value to *Variant* and hope that Excel will be able to work out what you want. But the better way is to examine your data column and look up the type of value you actually have there.

Next, given you are looking for a number which you have assigned to a Variant and Excel, in consequence, managed to find the string-equivalent of that number, that would be the functions return value, a text string. In most cases Excel is quite generous in this sort of situations but if it does complain about "Data Type" then it's because you are trying to assign a text string to a variable of Long data type.

Other than that, as @Michal Palko already pointed out, the ListBox's ListIndex is 0-based. If the numbers in your worksheet are 1-based the return of VLOOKUP won't be "totally different" but it will be from the adjacent row and therefore unexpected.

But I want to alert you to another possibility. As you know, you can load many columns into your list box. You can show some of the columns and hide others but you can access them all with code like this:-

```
With ListBox1
    Debug.Print .List(.ListIndex, 3)
End With
```

This snippet will print out the value of the 3rd column in the row of `ListIndex`. You might also assign this value to a variable and, perhaps, have no need for VLOOKUP.

Comment: thanks! Actually this is more simple method to display. I will use this for all date avalible in List box. But the problem is when value is not avalible in Listbox. For example: List box display 10 columns with main value. After click the button, I would like to show also more details from not the same Sheet. Off course infomation must have some common identification like "ID Number". I will try working at my type of var.

Comment: In such cases I am inclined to add a hidden column to the list box that contains the row number, if it's available at the time of populating the list box, rather than looking it up later. If there is a direct correlation between the ListIndex and the row number I would also rather calculate the row number from the list index, either at the time of populating the list or upon demand. Doing so would save you the hassle of Vlookup and render the extra sheet column redundant.